# I have problems getting this javascript + asp.net to work

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i have this little proyect that brings a little window to take the data from the "modal" window to the main but i have problems putting in to work.

The index:

```
%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebTest.Index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="Ventana.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="valor1" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="valor2" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdRutPersona" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAbrirPopup" runat="server" Text="Abrir" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the .cs part of index:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebTest
{
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                btnAbrirPopup.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:Asistencia('txtIdRutPersona');");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the "persona" window that is the page that bind the data to the index:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Persona.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebTest.Persona" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Ventana.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function cerrar()
            {
                self.close();
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Buscar" method="post" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRut" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Aplicar" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnCerrar" runat="server" Text="Cerrar" />
        </div>
        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the .cs part of "persona":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebTest
{
    public partial class Persona : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ViewState["form"] = Request.QueryString["formname"];
                ViewState["txtRut"] = Request.QueryString["txtRut"];
                ViewState["postBack"] = Request.QueryString["postBack"];

                btnOk.Attributes.Add("onClick", $"window.opener.SetCodigo({ViewState["form"]},{ViewState["txtRut"]},{ViewState["postBack"]})");
                btnCerrar.Attributes.Add("onClick", "cerrar()");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the js:

```
var VentanaOrigen;

function Asistencia(txtRut) {

    popUp = window.open('Persona.aspx?formname=' + document.forms[0].name + '&txtRut=' + txtRut, '', 'width=430,height=300,left=200,top=150,resizable=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes');

}

function SetCodigo(formulario, txtIdRutPersona, IdRutPersona, IPostback) {

    eval('var theform = document.' + formulario + ';');
    VentanaOrigen.close();
    theform.elements[txtIdRutPersona].value = IdRutPersona;

    if (IPostback)
        __doPostBack(txtIdRutPersona, '');

}
```

sorry to bother with the large text but im kinda frustated right now, thanks!

Comment: What exact problem do you have? Do you get an error? What doesn't run as expected?

Comment: It doesnt work, the data from the "persona" windows doesnt comes to the main, and the error is throwing comes in the attribute.add it brings it to the hltm with the commas and blank up front and the back

Comment: The function `Asistencia` will move the browser to the URL you specified - which is confusing me as you said "Modal". This isn't how you do a modal.  Also you need to return `false` from the function otherwise you get a POST.

There are many simple examples of doing a modal in Javascript like: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult what you're trying to achieve. I am guessing:

index.aspx has a button to load a popup (which is not modal)
The button passes in the ID of textbox `txtIdRutPersona`

**Index.aspx**

```
<input type="button" value="Abrir" onclick="Asistencia('<%= txtIdRutPersona.ClientID %>')" />
```

Use client ID in case ASP.NET generates a different ID. Also you should get errors if you change ID (on a later date).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Asistencia(txtIdRutPersonaID) {
         popUp = window.open('Persona.aspx?txtIdRutPersonaID=' + txtIdRutPersonaID, '', 'width=430,height=300,left=200,top=150,resizable=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes');
    }
</script>
```

**persona.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRut" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>            
<input type="button" value="Aplicar" onclick="SetCodigo('<%= TxtIdRutPersonaID %>', '<%= txtRut.ClientID %>')" />
<input type="button" value="Cerrar" onclick="cerrar()" />
```

You can send the data to index.aspx using window.opener and the ID from index.aspx (txtIdRutPersonaID)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetCodigo(txtIdRutPersonaID, txtRutID) {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            var txtIdRutPersona = window.opener.document.getElementById(txtIdRutPersonaID);
            // txtIdRutPersona is the textbox from index.aspx
            txtIdRutPersona.value = document.getElementById(txtRutID).value;
        }
        window.close();
    }

    function cerrar()
    {
        self.close();
    }
</script>
```

**persona.aspx.cs**

```
public string TxtIdRutPersonaID
{
    get
    {
        return Request.QueryString["txtIdRutPersonaID"];
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use ASP.NET code behind to generate onclick event (but theres no good reason to). E.g:

```
btnOk.Attributes.Add("onclick", $"SetCodigo('{txtIdRutPersonaID}','{txtRut.ClientID}')");
```

Likewise, theres no reason to use `ViewState["form"]`, `ViewState["txtRut"]` & `ViewState["postBack"]`